# Delete array items from object in localstorage - Ionic App

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have an `Ionic` App where I am storing the data in the `localStorage`. The requirement is that I want to delete some items from an array in an object on the `localStorage` based on user `click`.

I have the below code but somehow not working. Please suggest where I am doing the mistake.

**home.html:**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items[0]">
    <ion-item no-lines class="items" *ngIf='this.items!= 0' (click)="deletereminder(item)">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <h3 ion-text class="items">
                    Reminder {{item [0] + 1}}
                </h3>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                <h3 ion-text class="items">
                    {{item [1] | date:'medium'}}
                </h3>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col style="text-align: right;">
                <h3 ion-text class="itemdelete">
                    <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
                </h3>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
</ng-container>
```

**home.ts:**

```js
 deletereminder(item){
    var newObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data'));
    console.log("index to delete",item);
    newObj.data.splice(item, 1)
    localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(newObj));
  }
```

my `localStorage` looks like this:

```
Key   : Data
Value : {"data":[[0,"1600074900000"],[1,"1600679760000"]]}
```

Issue is the above `home.ts` is deleting the complete `array` instead of item clicked.

The function `(click)="deletereminder(item)"` returns the correct item to be deleted. example if i click on any item `0,"1600074900000"`, it will return `0,"1600074900000"`. I have checked through console.log(item).

But it is not deleting the item i am selecting. Instead it is deleting items from top of the array. example, if array has 3 records, it is deleting records from top to bottom. And also when it reaches the last record, it is not deleting the last record.

Comment: Can you post both `item` and the array/object you are setting in local storage so that we can have better idea to play around.

Comment: How is your UI looks like with your code, can you post image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution with the below updated code.

In home.html, below update is done:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items[0];let index = index" >
    <ion-item no-lines  class="items"  *ngIf='this.allObj1 != 0' (click)="deletereminder(index)">
```

In home.ts, below update is done:

```
deletereminder(index){
    var newObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data'));
    var indextodelete = index;
    newObj.data.splice(indextodelete, 1)
    localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(newObj));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `update` the value in your `localStorage`. `removeItem()` only remove an item by key from localStorage. So Instead of deleting the key, just set it again with the new **Data** key:

1. `const newObj = localStorage.getItem("Data")`
2. Remove the `index` from `object`
3. `localStorage.setItem("Data", newObj )`

It's better that when you want to store your object on the `localStorage` use `JSON.stringfy` like this:

```js
localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify( {"data":[[0,"1600074900000"],[1,"1600679760000"]]}));
```

So when you want to get the object and modify that you can do something like this:

```
let DataObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data'));
```

So, if you store using `JSON.strinigfy()` in your `home.ts` try this:

**home.ts**

```js
deletereminder(item){
  let newObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data'));
  newObj.data.forEach((element, index) => {
    if(element[0] == item) {
       newObj.data.splice(index, 1)
    }
  })
  localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(newObj));
}
```

Comment: I tried the below but not working. Splice is not working. `const newObj = localStorage.getItem("rp_data")
    
    // Remove the index from object
    newObj.splice(index,1);

    localStorage.setItem("rp_data", newObj )`

Comment: I added some point for you to my answer. look at that. You have to use `JSON.stringify()` & `JSON.parse()` after that You will have a object of data. get the array out of it and then use splice. OK?

Comment: I added `deletereminder()` function for you too. In addition your `*ngFor` in your template is not correct

Comment: I tried your query but nothing is happening. I have updated the `deletereminder()` and also provided issue i am facing with this new function.

Comment: actually the `if(element[0] == item)` is always false and hence not working. can you suggest?

Comment: Any update on how to find the index of the item clicked? If i can retrieve the index, then the issue is resolved.

Comment: I don't get what is really your problem, but I think your `ngFor` in tmplete is wrong and this `*ngFor="let item of items[0]"` should be replaced with `*ngFor="let item of items"` But if it is not the problem, provide a sample code on Stackblitz of your code and place the link in your question that everyone can help you better.